# Can WP8 app run on WP8.1 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I developed a few apps for windows phone 8. I'm not sure why I want to put the effort and upgrade them to 8.1 apps since I understood that version 8 apps also work on version 8.1. Is that correct?

Please let me know why as a developer I want to "upgrade" to make WP8.1 apps instead of WP8.0 apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your existing WP8 app will run on WP8.1 directly without any change.

If you want to utilize latest feature introduced in WP8.1 in your app then you have to retarget your app to 8.1 then only it can use those features.
Example : integrating your app with cortana, utilizing universal template for both wp8.1 and windows8.1 etc.

If you don't want to do that still your app will work fine on wp8.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dvir , WP8 apps are still working on WP8.1

Comment: Thanks, can you please answer the second part?
"why as a developer I want to "upgrade" to make WP8.1 apps instead of WP8.0 apps."